# How can I import a Blender 3D model with a texture using Three.js?

Tags: node.js, three.js, blender

I created a very simple cube using Blender and exported it using the [Three.js Blender Exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender).

I am now attempting to load the exported model and apply a texture using Node. When I run the script, I see no error. What am I doing wrong?

```
'use strict';

const JSDOM = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
const THREE = require('three');

const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>`);

global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');

const loadTexture = (path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

        loader.load(
            path,

            // success
            (texture) => resolve(texture),

            // progress
            undefined,

            // error
            (error) => reject(error)
        );
    });
};

const loadGeometry = (path) => {
    const loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        loader.load(
            path,

            // success
            (geometry) => resolve(geometry),

            // progress
            undefined,

            // error
            (error) => reject(error)
        );
    });
};

const createObject = () => {
    return Promise.all([
        loadTexture('./image.jpg'),
        loadGeometry('./cube.json')
    ]).then(results => {
        const texture = results[0];
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
        const geometry = results[1];
        const object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        return object;
    });
};

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

createObject()
    .then(object => {
        scene.add(object);

        console.log('Success!');
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error.message));
```

Here is the model I am using:

```
{
    "normals":[-5.32907e-15,-1,2.98023e-08,1.06581e-14,1,-2.98023e-08,1,4.47034e-08,2.83122e-07,-2.83122e-07,-7.45059e-08,1,-1,-1.3411e-07,-2.23517e-07,2.38419e-07,1.78814e-07,-1],
    "faces":[33,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,33,4,7,6,5,1,1,1,1,33,0,4,5,1,2,2,2,2,33,1,5,6,2,3,3,3,3,33,2,6,7,3,4,4,4,4,33,4,0,3,7,5,5,5,5],
    "metadata":{
        "normals":6,
        "faces":6,
        "type":"Geometry",
        "vertices":8,
        "generator":"io_three",
        "uvs":0,
        "version":3
    },
    "vertices":[1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1],
    "uvs":[]
}
```

Comment: I don't see a renderer in your code, so nothing would appear... are you seeing no output at all but expecting `Success!`? Also note that jsdom probably does not support WebGL, you may need node-webgl or a headless browser here.

Comment: Hi Don, thanks for your feedback. You are right about no renderer. For now, my goal is to test loading of the model and texture. Once that works, I will proceed to implement rendering. I wonder if node-webgl is necessary to even load the model? Something seems to be preventing model load.

Comment: Since others can't run this code without your model, what do you see? Does any `console.log` output appear? Consider logging when the texture and model load or fail rather than resolving/rejecting immediately to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Just updated the question with the model :) No output appears with `console.log()`. But I just added a `.catch()` within `createObject()`, and 'lo and behold, I get an error message now: `THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D`. It then appears that `scene.add(object)` is causing this problem.

Comment: Ah nevermind. I get that error because then in the `.catch()` block `undefined` is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got something almost working:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const JSDOM = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
const THREE = global.THREE = require('three');
require('three/examples/js/renderers/Projector');
const CanvasRenderer = require('three/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer');
const Canvas = require('canvas');

const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>`);

global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');

const loadTexture = (url) => {
    const loader = new THREE.FileLoader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('loading texture');

        loader.load(
            url,

            // success
            (texture) => {
                console.log('loaded texture');
                resolve(texture);
            },

            // progress
            undefined,

            // error
            (error) => {
                console.log('error loading texture');
                reject(error);
            }
        );
    });
};

const loadGeometry = (url) => {
    const loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('loading geometry');

        loader.load(
            url,

            // success
            (geometry) => {
                console.log('loaded geometry');
                resolve(geometry);
            },

            // progress
            undefined,

            // error
            (error) => {
                console.log('error loading geometry');
                reject(error);
            }
        );
    });
};

const createObject = () => {
    return Promise.all([
        loadTexture('http://localhost:8000/image.jpg'),
        loadGeometry('http://localhost:8000/cube.json')
    ]).then(results => {
        const texture = results[0];
        const geometry = results[1];
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
        const object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        return object;
    });
};

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const canvas = new Canvas(800, 800);
const renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
});

camera.position.z = 5;

canvas.style = {};

renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);
renderer.setSize(800, 800);

createObject()
    .then(object => {
        scene.add(object);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        const out = fs.createWriteStream('./rendered.png');
        const canvasStream = canvas.pngStream();
        canvasStream.on('data', function (chunk) { out.write(chunk); });
        canvasStream.on('end', function () { console.log('done'); });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error.message));
```

Except it renders a blank, transparent PNG.